# Complex numbers and matrix calculation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel has support for complex numbers, *eg: `=IMSUM("5+2i","6+2i")`*, and matrix calculations *eg: `=MMULT(B7:D9,F3:F5)`*.

However putting complex values into the the cells with existing matrix operations produces an error. Is there a way you can perform matrix calculations with complex values in Excel?

I'm on the Excel 2010 beta on Windows 7 and open to alternative applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine complex arithmetic and matrix arithmetic in Excel because the complex functions return results in text format whereas the matrix functions require numeric input.

[Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/) (a commercial application) and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) (online engine from the makers of Mathematica) handles complex matrix arithmetic. Try putting

```
{{(0+1i),-1},{1,0}}.{{(2-5i),2},{3,4}}
```

into Wolfram Alpha. It returns the result (and many other types of info) in graphical format but you can also have it converted to Mathematica text form.

Comment: oh I wasn't aware Wolfram Alpha had matrix support, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a minimal bit of VBA, if you write (in VBA) a function `real_mat()` which turns your complex matrix `{a}` into a matrix twice as big: `{real(a),-im(a);im(a),real(a)}`
and another function `complex_mat` which takes a real mat and converts it back to the original complex form, then all Excel's worksheet functions you can do on real matrices can be done on `real_mat()` and they work as the equivalent functions would on complex values.

It works for `+`, `-`, `mmult`, `minverse` and `mtranspose`, note that `mtranspose` of a `real_mat()` type performs the complex conjugate - which is usually what you want to do.

For example, you would sum a range `a`and `b` of complex numbers and invert the result using the formula `=complex_mat(minverse(real_mat(a) + real_mat(b)))`